# Entity framework hot to manage large projects?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a DB with many tables (near to 400)

For now we must build the model using dbfirst aproach.

1. What is the best aproach for build the models ?
2. Can we compile the entire model as a dll ?
3. How can I do, to reuse the model on diferent projects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Best for doing what?! If you need to build your project quick, I recommend you `Database-First` approach.But I has some limits but fast . If you use `Model-First` you can build your project fast , buy same as Database-First , it has some limits , but if time is not your problem , so you can use `Class-First` (Code-First) approach. It is more flexible that the others.

2 - Yes you can. If you are using n-tier architecture, you can create your DAL layer by create a `Class Project` and put your `EDMX` or your `POCO` entities into it.

3 - I believe that Code-First is better that the others. Depend on my experiment using POCO entities can help you more for using variety database engines.

Generally selecting your witch approach you want to use is depended to your project circumstances. For big project I recommend Code-First approach. But keep it in your mind that in all EF approaches , you must take care of your queries.

EX: A big mistake that is saw in new programmers code :

Code 1 :

```
DataContext.Table1.ToList().Where(x => x.Username == "Ali")
```

Code 2 :

```
DataContext.Table1.Where(x => x.Username == "Ali").ToList()
```

The first code fetch all records and then take one of them , but the second code just fetch one record ,and if your Table1 has 10 million records , a terrible mistake will happen :)) .So during developing your project be aware of such these mistake. It is more important that select your approach approach :)

Good luck

Comment: What kind of things must consider "PERFORMANCE THINGS" When build a large model =?

Comment: I believe even a professional strategy can takes too performances. It is your responsible to keep your code clean not your selected approach . Specially is this case(I mean EF and its approach)